# Why Vigyan Bhairav Tantra have a different story of enlightenment?

Tags: vedas, meditation, enlightenment

Vigyan Bhairav Tantra is know for its 108 methods of meditation which I think are not in vedas or not given by patanjali rishi.

So what is the essence of this book, Do we know when it was written (people says it was written by Lord Shiva).

Not a fan of any guru as if now, but Osho and many gurus have been talking about power of now, they just mean that living in the present moment is the way to enlightenment.

How true is that it is different than the knowledge or the way vedas taught us in the path of self realization.

Because they only talk about the power of observation, am i missing tons of things here?

Comment: VBT is an [Agama](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12282/what-are-the-agama-scriptures-are-they-related-to-shruti-vedas/16541#16541) Text..It was spoken by Bhairva (Lord Shiva)..also its virtually impossible to ascertain the time when a particular scripture was spoken/composed or made available to us..

Comment: @Rickross So is it a valid scripture same as Manusmriti & upnishads ?

Comment: Yes of course..Its an Agama Shastra..Vedas,Upanishads,Smritis,Vedangas,Puranas,Agamas etc are all Hindu Scriptures..

Comment: Observation separates body from real 'I' which is in indirect accordance of 'Neti Neti' of Vedas. Vijnabhairav techniques are application of science described in Vedas. And Moreover, we have lost many shakhas. Every eternal knowledge must be in the Vedas.

Comment: ManuSmiriti is a smiriti (relevant for that time and location) where as Vigyana Bhairav Tantra is an Agama (as correctly pointed out by @Rickross) is a Shruti hence Agamas are also called VedaAgamas. ManuSmiriti was written before Agamas were revealed to SaptaRishis, different Agamas were revealed to different persons (Devi, Kartikeya, Rishi etc).