# which hindu sect's sectarian literature places itself having more authority than veda

Tags: vedas, sects

http://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduism/hinduism-and-diversity.asp
this above url mentions that:

> The Vedas are considered supreme and inviolable. However, not all Hindu traditions hold them with the same esteem. Followers of certain Tantra and Shakta etc. traditions recognize Agama and other Saiva texts as supreme instead of the Vedas.

**Now my question is that**: please **tell the exact verse number** of the sectarian scriptures of those sects of tantra and shakta etc. traditions in which there is any 'explicitly written reference' in their scriptures, which says that - "their sectarian literature has more canonical pramana/authority than veda".

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Vidya#Major_texts mentions SriVidya own major texts. Can you please please mention in its text where it is mentioned that Vedas are not canonical? In Lingayat's basavanna's vachana i have found the exact verse where he mentions about vedas to be not canonical. But I am unable to find the same for SriVidya sect. Can you please mention the exact verse number of SriVidya's own text, where they say that it is higher in authority than veda?

Comment: now also see additional related new question: 
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24657/in-which-verse-of-srividya-sects-sacred-texts-it-is-mentioned-that-vedas-are-no

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury are you sure what are you talking about ?

Comment: Sorry made a mistake. Sri Vidya doesn't reject the authority of the Vedas.

Comment: Do not add bold to the normal text without adding any other words or usefulinfo. It bumps the question unnecessarily.

Comment: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12282/what-are-the-agama-scriptures-are-they-related-to-shruti-vedas?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment30490_12282 and also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16541/13287  ( The Agamas do not derive their authority from the Vedas, but are not antagonistic to them. ) ( In Krita Yuga, Vedas are the predominant Hindu shastra, in Treta, the Smritis, in Dwapara, it is the Samhitas and religious lore (Puranas) but in Kali Yuga all the above shastras have lost their powers. Hence Shiva created the Tantras or the mass of Agamas and Nigamas )