# What are nigamas, agamas, tantras and yamalas?

Tags: scripture

How is any scripture classified as nigamas, agamas, tantras and yamalas? What is the origin of each? Where can I find them online?

Comment: Related or a possible duplicate of [What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/5212)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma it answers to an extent. Where can I find them online?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma sorry for the trouble. You can close it. I will search for them in  the given links.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I don't see the option

Comment: @krr did you get "this question already has an answer here"

Comment: Click on "that solved my problem" @krr

Comment: @AkshayKumarS  no, I am using app. I don't see what you said.