# Under what category of texts does Narada Pancharatra come?

Tags: vaishnavism, pancharatra, narada

I have seen the term Panchatantra being used for Panchatantra agamas.Under what category does Narada Pancharatra come?

Comment: Related-[What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12282/what-are-the-agama-scriptures-are-they-related-to-shruti-vedas) You can go through the exhaustive answer given by Rickross Ji....If any doubt persists do let me know :)